# Read the full string in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

We have a macro written in VBA within Word that reads data from an Excel file. The HTML body of an email is stored in a field within Excel.

The field is not completely read and the text is shrunk.

```vb
    Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument                                               ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc when Macro run) as "masterDoc"

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord                   ' jump to the last active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)
    lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord                  ' retrieve the record number of the last active record so we know when to stop

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord                  ' jump to the first active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)

    Do While lastRecordNum > 0                                                   ' create a loop, lastRecordNum is used to end the loop by setting to zero (see below)

        masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument                    ' Identify that we are creating a word docx (and no e.g. an email)
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord              ' Limit the selection to just one document by setting the start ...
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord               ' ... and end points to the active record
        masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False                                        ' run the MailMerge based on the above settings (i.e. for one record)

        Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument                                           ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc after running the MailMerge) as "singleDoc"

        'region Send email
        Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        Dim pdfFilePath As String
        pdfFilePath = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf"
        
        Dim HTMLBody As String
        HTMLBody = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("EmailBody").Value
                
        With oItem
            .To = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("EmailAddress").Value
            .Subject = "Test"
            .HTMLBody = HTMLBody 
            '.HTMLBody = "Hello, this is me sending an email to you. We need to know some things. The things we need to know are if we're able to send out emails to anyone anyplace at anytime. Also, why are strings cut of at a specific length? Can you help me with this? Thank you, the wolf of Wall Street"
            .Attachments.Add Source:=pdfFilePath, Type:=olByValue
            .Send
        End With
        'endregion

        singleDoc.Close False                                                    ' Close "singleDoc", the variable "singleDoc" can now be used for the next record when created

        If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then     ' test if we have just created a document for the last record
            lastRecordNum = 0                                                    ' if so we set lastRecordNum to zero to indicate that the loop should end
        Else
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord           ' otherwise go to the next active record
        End If

    Loop                                                                         ' loop back to the Do start

End Sub                                                                          ' Mark the end of the Subroutine
```

In the example above the text field in Excel is read until "Thank you" the rest of the text is not available in the variable 'HTMLBody'. What can be done to get the full length of the string here?

It seems this line is not retrieving the full string:

```vb
masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("EmailBody").Value
```

Is there a workaround?

---

It's a mailmerge so the DataSource in this case is an Excel file. The line `masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("EmailBody").Value` retrieves the value in the Excel file from column "EmailBody" but it only retrieves the first 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the value in your Word Datasourc "EmailBody" i see no reference to Excel in your code. Where does your Datasource come from, did you first import the date from Excel?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's a mailmerge so the DataSource in this case is an Excel file. The code `masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("EmailBody").Value` retrieves the value in the Excel file from column "EmailBody" but it only retrieves the first 255 characters.